# IE box model error

Tags: html, css

I have a footer, below a textarea, containing a list and two buttons (all inline) within a div  with the id #share-something. For some reason it is placed differently in Internet Explorer. I want it to look the same in IE as it does in Chrome. What am I doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/h3twR/

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough, IE7 seems to be fine for me, but 8 & 9 are off. If you have an IE-only stylesheet (using conditional comments), you can add this:

```
#share-something-container textarea {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

*:first-child+html #share-something-container textarea {
margin-bottom: 0px;  /* targets ie7 and undoes the margin above, as IE7 is okay */
}
```

This doesn't explain *why* 8 & 9 behave differently, but I've long since given up looking for logic and reason in IE.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some kind of difference between IE8/9 and the other browsers and how they're rendering TEXTAREA.

It looks like you just have to set TEXTAREA to display block.   It seems some browsers behave differently in this situation as they will see all elements as inline and generate extra white space.  However, setting it to display:inline doesn't seem to have the reverse effect, so it's weird like that.

Here's a solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/h3twR/2/

I simply added this:

```
#share-something-container textarea {
    ...
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

And it appeared to render more consistently.  IE7 seems to be off a little bit more.  But hopefully this helps a little.

Cheers!